# Deleting a value from database based on data coming sent from a form - Django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to implement newsletter/email subscription for my project.
I created a model which only stores the email and the timestamp and uses SendGrid to send emails to the users who subscribed.

I want to include an unsubscribe button inside the emails I send them. When the user clicks unsubscribe link in the mail it appends the `id` of the value in `db` to the `url` and redirects to `cancelsub.html` where I am accessing it.

In `cancelsub.html` I have a form with a submit button which when a user clicks should delete the value from db. It is not working for some reason.

Models.py--

```
class NewsletterUser(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField(null=True)
    date_added =  models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
```

Views.py--

```
def NewsLetter(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email_input = request.POST.get('email_value')
        new = NewsletterUser(email=email_input)
        new.save()
        sendEmail(email_input)
   return render(request,"pages/index.html")

def DeleteNewsLetter(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        del_id = request.POST.get('id_value')
        NewsletterUser.objects.filter(id= del_id).delete()
    return render(request, "newsletter/CancelSubscription.html")
```

cancelsub.html--

```
<form id="cancel-subscription-form" method="POST">
  {% csrf_token %}
  <div class="email-and-btn">
  <button class="btn btn-danger mb-2 art-digest-btn" id="cancel-btn" type="submit" value="">Yes, Cancel It</button>
  </div>   
</form>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        
<script>
  var current_url = window.location.href
  var id = current_url.split('?')[1]
  id_int = parseInt(id)
  $("#cancel-btn").val(id_int);

  $(document).on('submit','#cancel-subscription-form',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'{% url "DeleteNewsLetter" %}',
                data:
                {
                    id_value: parseInt($("#cancel-btn").val()),
                    csrfmiddlewaretoken:$('input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]').val(),
                },
                success:function(){
            
                }
                })
            });
        </script>
    </div>
```

urls.py--

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.NewsLetter, name='NewsLetter'),
    path('CancelSubscription', views.CancelSubscription, name='CancelSubscription'),
    path('', views.DeleteNewsLetter, name='DeleteNewsLetter'),
]
```

When I execute this code out, instead of deleting the value from database, it adds a blank value into the db. I'm confused as to why this is happening.

It'd be really helpful if anyone guide me where I went wrong!.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that the URL that you send on the email is something like this: http://mywebsite.com/unsubscribe/?9

So you get the "9" with the javascript code. You don't need the javascript if you give a name to your value like this: http://mywebsite.com/unsubscribe/?user_id=9

Now, you can just doing this:

```
<form id="cancel-subscription-form" method="POST" action="{% url "DeleteNewsLetter" %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="email-and-btn">
        <button name="id_value" class="btn btn-danger mb-2 art-digest-btn" id="cancel-btn" type="submit" value="{{request.GET.user_id}}">Yes, Cancel It</button>
    </div>   
</form>
```

I think that your problem is in the javascript code, so simplify and deleting it probably your system works.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response. I tried your suggestion, it still does the same thing, instead of deleting the value it adds another value to the database. Do you know why this is happening?

Comment: Can you share your urls.py?

Comment: Sure, ill update the question

Comment: I updated the question, please have a look

Comment: Ok, the problem is that you have the same url for two different views. Adding “action” to your form probably works but I suggest you to change this and always separate the urls with different views. I will change my answer adding the action to the form

Comment: RIGHT. I DONT EVEN KNOW THIS DIDNT STRIKE ME. IT STARTED WORKING AS SOON AS I GAVE URL. THANKS A LOT. I WAS ON THIS ISSUE SINCE A LONG TIME.

Comment: You are welcome! Next step, you must to think about to pass something different to the user id from the email. For security reason, someone could unsubscribe all your users if he discovers your method. Think about encode a strong field different from the id or something else

Comment: Yes, for sure, just wanted to make sure everything works before trying to encrypt the passed parameter.